# Is there a backwards compatible method for changing the return type of a GraphQL Mutation?

Tags: graphql, backwards-compatibility

I have a GraphQL project where many of the mutations return a simple boolean for success (union'ed with an error type).

```
# An object wrapper for a un/successful mutation result
type MutationResult {
    # whether the mutation was successful
    success: Boolean!
}

# An indicator that a user-error
type FieldError {
    field: String!
    message: String!
    type: String
}

# A wrapper object around [FieldError] for use in interfaces and unions.
type FieldErrors {
    fieldErrors: [FieldError!]!
}
```

One such example is this `addPhoneNumber` mutation

```
extend type Mutation {
    # All Mutations that can be applied to a User
    user: UserMutation!
}

union AddPhoneNumberResult = FieldErrors | MutationResult

type UserMutation {
    # Add phone number to the user's account
    addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String!): AddPhoneNumberResult! @RequireAuthorization(secure: true)

# Several other mutations...
```

I would like to change the return type of this mutation to include more details about the result, like this.

```
union AddPhoneNumberResult = FieldErrors | PhoneNumber

type PhoneNumber {
    # A phone number associated with this account
    phoneNumber: String!

    # Whether or not this phone number has been verified via the SMS verification code
    verified: Boolean!

    factorStatus: FactorStatus!
}

enum FactorStatus {
    PENDING_ACTIVATION,
    ACTIVE,
    EXPIRED
}
```

However, it occurs to me that this is a breaking change for any client that is calling this mutation. The request body would necessarily change from.

```
mutation AddPhoneNumber {
    user {
        addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: "8675309") {
            ... on FieldErrors {
                fieldErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }

            ... on MutationResult {
                success
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
mutation AddPhoneNumber {
    user {
        addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: "8675309") {
            ... on FieldErrors {
                fieldErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }

            ... on PhoneNumber {
                phoneNumber
                verified
                factorStatus
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the moment we deployed the change to the GraphQL service.

We can't change `MutationResult` itself because is used by many other mutations; changing it would essentially be adding a nullable field that no other mutation would fill out. Any other change I can think of to the response falls into the same trap.

The only backwards compatible way I can think make this change is to introduce an entirely new mutation and wire it up separately, leaving the `addPhoneNumber` mutation alone. All the advice I can find on backwards compatibility seems focused on queries where the system was designed with the foresight of granular types. I've not found a similar level of guide for mutations and mutation responses.

Is there something else I'm not seeing?

The server is a Java project using [`com.graphql-java`](https://www.graphql-java.com/), if that makes a difference in strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/#breaking-changes) for a real world example for handling breaking changes in GraphQL.

Basically the idea is that you need to do it step by step. First, make the `AddPhoneNumberResult` can support all the possible union members :

```
union AddPhoneNumberResult = FieldErrors | MutationResult | PhoneNumber
```

Then notify the API users that `MutationResult` will be sooner or later be removed. Give them appropriate time to update their codes to use the new union member. Otherwise , they may face a risk that their application will suddenly not work if server has some updates.

In the server side , you can consider to monitor the usage of `MutationResult` and actually delete it when you feel comfortable its usage is low enough.

*P.S `@deprecated` allows to document the deprecated reasons for a field.Most GraphQL tools will detect it and give user warning if they try to use a deprecated field. But it only can apply on the field and enum value. There is a [discussion](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/197#issue-166400619) before to make it also can be used with union member but I don't know its latest status. Just an FYI.*

Comment: I had a thought about adding to the union, but I wasn't sure how to execute it. How would you wire up a data fetcher that could appropriately respond based on whether a client requested the MutationResult or the PhoneNumber response? Or do you need to make the one data fetcher always return both?

Comment: The data fetcher can return any type of object.  And you need to implement a [`TypeResolver`](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/schema#datafetcher-and-typeresolver) for the `AddPhoneNumberResult` type to resolve which actual GraphQL type should be given the object returned from the data fetcher. The `TypeResolutionEnvironment` instance will be given when implementing `TypeResolver`, you can try to see if you can make use of it to get which union members do the client specify in the query.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this if my mutation does not return a union already? It seems like the pure act of adding a union will break clients in that case.

Comment: @ArnoHilke I think it comes down to whether your clients are already using the `...on` FragmentSpread for the mutation result. If they are, they should have no trouble adding an additional `...on` fragment after the server is updated. You'll notice that none of my example queries reference the `AddPhoneNumberResult`, just the `FieldErrors` and `MutationResult` union members. However, I don't know if the `...on` Fragment is supported if the schema does not support a union type.

Answer (score 1):

Revisiting this for a different query that needed the same treatment, [Ken Chan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565175/1146608) answer was spot on for the schema change. The hard part was detecting in which result the user was requesting.

The specific implementation of course hinges on the language and GQL library the server is running. As I mentioned this server is running `graphql-java`, here is a java centric solution. I wrote a utility method that searches for the entity through the

```java
/**
 * Searches the client's query for the named entity
 *
 * @param environment the GraphQL data fetching environment passed to each data fetcher
 * @param entityName the name of the entity to search for
 * @return true if the entity of the given name appears in the query
 */
public static boolean entityRequested(
    DataFetchingEnvironment environment, @NotNull String entityName) {
  var selectionSet = environment.getOperationDefinition().getSelectionSet().getSelections();
  for (Selection selection : selectionSet) {
    if (searchSelection(selection, entityName)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
  
private static boolean searchSelection(Selection selection, String entityName) {
  if (selection instanceof Field) {
    if (searchField((Field) selection, entityName)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  if (selection instanceof FragmentSpread) {
    if (searchFragmentSpread((FragmentSpread) selection, entityName)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  if (selection instanceof InlineFragment) {
    if (searchInlineFragment((InlineFragment) selection, entityName)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
  
public static boolean searchField(Field field, String entityName) {
  if (entityName.equals(field.getName())) {
    return true;
  }
  var selectionSet = field.getSelectionSet();
  if (null == selectionSet) {
    return false;
  }
  for (Selection selection : selectionSet.getSelections()) {
    if (searchSelection(selection, entityName)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
  
public static boolean searchFragmentSpread(FragmentSpread fragment, String entityName) {
  if (entityName.equals(fragment.getName())) {
    return true;
  }
  for (Directive directive : fragment.getDirectives()) {
    if (entityName.equals(directive.getName())) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
  
public static boolean searchInlineFragment(InlineFragment fragment, String entityName) {
  if (entityName.equals(fragment.getTypeCondition().getName())) {
    return true;
  }
  var selectionSet = fragment.getSelectionSet();
  if (null == selectionSet) {
    return false;
  }
  for (Selection selection : selectionSet.getSelections()) {
    if (searchSelection(selection, entityName)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is overkill for the response type. After implementing it, I realized the return type was always in a `FragmentSpread` object type, corresponding with the `...on` syntax in the mutation.

You use the utility in the DataFetcher, using the varv.either library, like so

```java
@Component
public class AddPhoneNumberMutation implements DataFetcher<Object> {

  @Override
  public Object get(DataFetchingEnvironment environment) {
    Either<FieldError, AddPhoneNumberResult> addPhoneNumberResult = 

    if (addPhoneNumberResult.isLeft()) {
      return new FieldErrors(addPhoneNumberResult.getLeft());
    }

    if (entityRequested(environment, "PhoneNumber")) {
      // If the query included the PhoneNumber entity return the new response type
      return addPhoneNumberResult.get();
    } else {
      // Else, return the "basic" boolean MutationResult
      return MutationResult.success();
    }
  }
}
```